# ionic3 android build error: Timeout waiting to lock

Tags: ionic3

I updated macOS from EL Capitan to High Sierra and installed ionic3.
`ionic serve` succeeded, but I encountered build error in `ionic cordova run android --device`.

I encounter the error below

- Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
  Could not create service of type GeneralCompileCaches using GradleScopeCompileServices.createGeneralCompileCaches().
- Timeout waiting to lock Build Output Cleanup Cache (/Path/to/myapp/platforms/android/.gradle/buildOutputCleanup). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.
- Could not create service of type TaskArtifactStateRepository using 
  TaskExecutionServices.createTaskArtifactStateRepository().
  Timeout waiting to lock task history cache 
  (/Path/to/myapp/platforms/android/.gradle/4.1/taskHistory). It is 
  currently in use by another Gradle instance.

I delete lock file and kill process again and again, but I can not resolve this problem.

I tried to remove platform and add,change gradle version, reinstall AndroidStudio, reinstall npm, reinstall ionic and cordova, but these did not work. please help me.

Logs in my first build is below

```
Running app-scripts build: --platform android --target cordova
[18:18:19]  build dev started ...
[18:18:19]  clean started ...
[18:18:19]  clean finished in 3 ms
[18:18:19]  copy started ...
[18:18:20]  deeplinks started ...
[18:18:20]  deeplinks finished in 20 ms
[18:18:20]  transpile started ...
[18:18:25]  transpile finished in 4.88 s
[18:18:25]  preprocess started ...
[18:18:25]  preprocess finished in 1 ms
[18:18:25]  webpack started ...
[18:18:25]  copy finished in 5.88 s
[18:18:33]  webpack finished in 7.82 s
[18:18:33]  sass started ...
Without `from` option PostCSS could generate wrong source map and will not find Browserslist config. Set it to CSS file path or to `undefined` to prevent this warning.
[18:18:34]  sass finished in 1.54 s
[18:18:34]  postprocess started ...
[18:18:34]  postprocess finished in 160 ms
[18:18:34]  lint started ...
[18:18:34]  build dev finished in 15.05 s
> cordova run android --device
Android Studio project detected

ANDROID_HOME=/Users/myAccount/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Users/myAccount/.jenv/versions/1.8.0.172
studio
:wrapper


BUILD SUCCESSFUL
 in 2s

1 actionable task: 1 executed

Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

[18:18:46]  lint finished in 11.83 s
publishNonDefault is deprecated and has no effect anymore. All variants are now published.

Observed package id 'tools' in inconsistent location '/Users/myAccount/Library/Android/sdk/tools_back' (Expected '/Users/myAccount/Library/Android/sdk/tools')

Already observed package id 'tools' in '/Users/myAccount/Library/Android/sdk/tools'. Skipping duplicate at '/Users/myAccount/Library/Android/sdk/tools_back'

Observed package id 'tools' in inconsistent location '/Users/myAccount/Library/Android/sdk/tools_back' (Expected '/Users/myAccount/Library/Android/sdk/tools')

Already observed package id 'tools' in '/Users/myAccount/Library/Android/sdk/tools'. Skipping duplicate at '/Users/myAccount/Library/Android/sdk/tools_back'
The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.

    at build_cdomysz0j2rea5ksz26ej40t2.run(/Path/to/myapp/platforms/android/app/build.gradle:143)

:CordovaLib:preBuild
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl

:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript

:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig

:CordovaLib:prepareLintJar
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues

:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources
:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources

:CordovaLib:platformAttrExtractor

:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest

:CordovaLib:javaPreCompileDebug

:CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes
 NO-SOURCE
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild

:app:compileDebugAidl

:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript

:app:checkDebugManifest

:app:generateDebugBuildConfig

:app:prepareLintJar

:app:generateDebugResValues
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources

:app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests

:app:processDebugManifest

:app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug

:CordovaLib:processDebugResources

:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not create service of type GeneralCompileCaches using GradleScopeCompileServices.createGeneralCompileCaches().

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 42s
23 actionable tasks: 23 executed
(node:93755) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: /Path/to/myapp/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not create service of type GeneralCompileCaches using GradleScopeCompileServices.createGeneralCompileCaches().

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 42s
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/Path/to/myapp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:169:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
(node:93755) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:93755) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

[OK] Your app has been deployed.
     Did you know you can live-reload changes from your app with --livereload?
```

Logs in my second build is below

```
Running app-scripts build: --platform android --target cordova
[18:21:20]  build dev started ...
[18:21:20]  clean started ...
[18:21:20]  clean finished in 3 ms
[18:21:20]  copy started ...
[18:21:20]  deeplinks started ...
[18:21:20]  deeplinks finished in 18 ms
[18:21:20]  transpile started ...
[18:21:25]  transpile finished in 4.95 s
[18:21:25]  preprocess started ...
[18:21:25]  preprocess finished in 1 ms
[18:21:25]  webpack started ...
[18:21:26]  copy finished in 6.23 s
[18:21:34]  webpack finished in 9.34 s
[18:21:34]  sass started ...
Without `from` option PostCSS could generate wrong source map and will not find Browserslist config. Set it to CSS file path or to `undefined` to prevent this warning.
[18:21:36]  sass finished in 1.41 s
[18:21:36]  postprocess started ...
[18:21:36]  postprocess finished in 21 ms
[18:21:36]  lint started ...
[18:21:36]  build dev finished in 16.26 s
> cordova run android --device
Android Studio project detected

ANDROID_HOME=/Users/myAccount/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Users/myAccount/.jenv/versions/1.8.0.172
studio
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
publishNonDefault is deprecated and has no effect anymore. All variants are now published.
The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.

    at build_cdomysz0j2rea5ksz26ej40t2.run(/Path/to/myapp/platforms/android/app/build.gradle:143)

[18:21:47]  lint finished in 11.03 s

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Timeout waiting to lock Build Output Cleanup Cache (/Path/to/myapp/platforms/android/.gradle/buildOutputCleanup). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.
Owner PID: unknown
Our PID: 93843
Owner Operation: unknown
Our operation:
Lock file: /Path/to/myapp/platforms/android/.gradle/buildOutputCleanup/cache.properties.lock

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 15s
(node:94025) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: /Path/to/myapp/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Timeout waiting to lock Build Output Cleanup Cache (/Path/to/myapp/platforms/android/.gradle/buildOutputCleanup). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.
Owner PID: unknown
Our PID: 93843
Owner Operation: unknown
Our operation:
Lock file: /Path/to/myapp/platforms/android/.gradle/buildOutputCleanup/cache.properties.lock

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 15s
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/Path/to/myapp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:169:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
    at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:346:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:567:12)
(node:94025) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:94025) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

[OK] Your app has been deployed.
     Did you know you can live-reload changes from your app with --livereload?
```

I deleted /Path/to/myapp/platforms/android/.gradle/buildOutputCleanup/cache.properties.lock and killed the process 93843.

And Logs in my third build is below

```
Starting app-scripts server: --address 0.0.0.0 --port 8100 --livereload-port 35729 --dev-logger-port 53703 --consolelogs
--nobrowser --iscordovaserve --platform android --target cordova - Ctrl+C to cancel
[18:25:24]  watch started ...
[18:25:24]  build dev started ...
[18:25:24]  clean started ...
[18:25:24]  clean finished in 2 ms
[18:25:24]  copy started ...
[18:25:25]  deeplinks started ...
[18:25:25]  deeplinks finished in 15 ms
[18:25:25]  transpile started ...
[18:25:30]  transpile finished in 5.46 s
[18:25:30]  preprocess started ...
[18:25:30]  preprocess finished in 1 ms
[18:25:30]  webpack started ...
[18:25:31]  copy finished in 6.55 s
[18:25:39]  webpack finished in 8.63 s
[18:25:39]  sass started ...
Without `from` option PostCSS could generate wrong source map and will not find Browserslist config. Set it to CSS file path or to `undefined` to prevent this warning.
[18:25:41]  sass finished in 1.71 s
[18:25:41]  postprocess started ...
[18:25:41]  postprocess finished in 89 ms
[18:25:41]  lint started ...
[18:25:41]  build dev finished in 16.36 s
[18:25:41]  watch ready in 16.58 s
[18:25:41]  dev server running: http://localhost:8100/

[OK] Development server running!
     Local: http://localhost:8100
     External: http://192.168.11.16:8100


> cordova run android --device
Android Studio project detected

ANDROID_HOME=/Users/myAccount/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Users/myAccount/.jenv/versions/1.8.0.172
studio
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 2 incompatible and 2 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

[18:25:53]  lint finished in 12.58 s
publishNonDefault is deprecated and has no effect anymore. All variants are now published.

Observed package id 'tools' in inconsistent location '/Users/myAccount/Library/Android/sdk/tools_back' (Expected '/Users/myAccount/Library/Android/sdk/tools')

Already observed package id 'tools' in '/Users/myAccount/Library/Android/sdk/tools'. Skipping duplicate at '/Users/myAccount/Library/Android/sdk/tools_back'
Observed package id 'tools' in inconsistent location '/Users/myAccount/Library/Android/sdk/tools_back' (Expected '/Users/myAccount/Library/Android/sdk/tools')

Already observed package id 'tools' in '/Users/myAccount/Library/Android/sdk/tools'. Skipping duplicate at '/Users/myAccount/Library/Android/sdk/tools_back'
The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.
    at build_cdomysz0j2rea5ksz26ej40t2.run(/Path/to/myapp/platforms/android/app/build.gradle:143)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not create service of type TaskArtifactStateRepository using TaskExecutionServices.createTaskArtifactStateRepository().
> Timeout waiting to lock task history cache (/Path/to/myapp/platforms/android/.gradle/4.1/taskHistory). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.
  Owner PID: unknown
  Our PID: 94601
  Owner Operation: unknown
  Our operation:
  Lock file: /Path/to/myapp/platforms/android/.gradle/4.1/taskHistory/taskHistory.lock

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 12s
(node:94546) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: /Path/to/myapp/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not create service of type TaskArtifactStateRepository using TaskExecutionServices.createTaskArtifactStateRepository().
> Timeout waiting to lock task history cache (/Path/to/myapp/platforms/android/.gradle/4.1/taskHistory). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.
  Owner PID: unknown
  Our PID: 94601
  Owner Operation: unknown
  Our operation:
  Lock file: /Path/to/myapp/platforms/android/.gradle/4.1/taskHistory/taskHistory.lock

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 12s
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/Path/to/myapp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:169:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
(node:94546) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:94546) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

ionic info

```
cli packages: (/Users/myAccount/.nodebrew/node/v8.10.0/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.9
    Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 25.2.5
    Node              : v8.10.0
    npm               : 5.6.0
    OS                : macOS High Sierra
    Xcode             : Xcode 9.3 Build version 9E145

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : /Users/myAccount/Library/Android/sdk

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by myself.It is caused by the path of my project.

I encountered this problem when I place it in sd card.
I copied it to home and tried to build, and it went well.